# Array.push replaces all my array elements with the last one inserted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var ship_array = new Array();

var ship_object = new Object();
    ship_object.builder_id = 0;
    ship_object.list_id = 0;
    ship_object.ship_id = 0;
    ship_object.title_id = 0;
```

Then in a save function, I do:

```
function saveAll() {
    // Array cleaning
    while (ship_array.length) { ship_array.pop(); }

    // Cyclic save function
    $.each($(".ship-block"), function () {
        ship_object.builder_id = parseInt($(this).attr("data-counter"));
        ship_object.list_id = list.id;
        ship_object.ship_id = parseInt($(this).attr("data-ship-id"));
        ship_array.push(ship_object);
    });
    console.log(ship_array);
}
```

While debugging with Chrome, every ship_object has the correct values in every cycle, but when I print the array, every object has the same values, which are all corresponding to the last one inserted. Literally have no clue why it is happening. Ideas?

Comment: Yes; You are adding *n* references to the *same* object, you need to add a `new ship_object()` if you want them to be distinct, currently you are just overwriting the properties of the same instance.

Comment: The objects are used by reference, so inside the loop the **same** object is referenced and updated, so the same values. **My Answer:** `function saveAll() {
    // Array cleaning
    ship_array = [];

    // Cyclic save function
    $(".ship-block").each(function () {
        var ship_object = {};
        ship_object.builder_id = parseInt($(this).attr("data-counter"));
        ship_object.list_id = list.id;
        ship_object.ship_id = parseInt($(this).attr("data-ship-id"));
        ship_array.push(ship_object);
    });
    console.log(ship_array);
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you are using the reference of the object and updating the same object again and again. Try creating a new object every time when the loop iterates,

```
function saveAll() {
    //while (ship_array.length) { ship_array.pop(); }
    ship_array = [];
    $(".ship-block").each(function () {
        ship_object = {}; // creating a new object here!!
        ship_object.builder_id = parseInt($(this).attr("data-counter"));
        ship_object.list_id = list.id;
        ship_object.ship_id = parseInt($(this).attr("data-ship-id"));
        ship_array.push(ship_object);
    });
    console.log(ship_array);
}
```

Comment: @Tushar I just tried to answer in the way user writes. you can update the same to my answer, below mine as a suggestion to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, your array contains references to the same object, you only update properties of that object.

You should create a new object for each array element. Note that you can that using an object literal syntax like so:

```
function saveAll() {
    // Array cleaning
    ship_array = [];

    // Cyclic save function
    $.each($(".ship-block"), function () {
        var ship_object = {
            builder_id: parseInt($(this).attr("data-counter")),
            list_id: list.id,
            ship_id: parseInt($(this).attr("data-ship-id"))
        };
        ship_array.push(ship_object);
    });
    console.log(ship_array);
}
```

Note that I also reinitialized the array with a new empty array (`[]`) rather than popping from it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone your object:

```
$.each($(".ship-block"), function () {
  var object = $.extend({}, ship_object);
  object.builder_id = ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to function scope, your pointer is being reused, and the pointer is being pushed to the stack rather than the object it is pointing to. Using an object literal within the callback should avoid reusing any pointers. and fix the issue.

```
function saveAll() {
    // Array cleaning
    while (ship_array.length) { ship_array.pop(); }

    // Cyclic save function
    $.each($(".ship-block"), function () {
        ship_array.push({
          builder_id: parseInt($(this).attr("data-counter")),
          list_id: list.id,
          ship_id: parseInt($(this).attr("data-ship-id"))
        });
    });
    console.log(ship_array);
}
```